# XSLT, create table header and rows

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following XML-structure:

```
<Tab4>
    <T4Head1>First Table header 1</T4Head1>
    <T4Head2>First Table header 2</T4Head2>
    <T4Head3>First Table header 3</T4Head3>
    <T4Head4>First Table header 4</T4Head4>
</Tab4>
<Tab4>
    <T4Col1>First Table row 1 column 1</T4Col1>
    <T4Col2>First Table row 1 column 2</T4Col2>
    <T4Col3>First Table row 1 column 3</T4Col3>
    <T4Col4>First Table row 1 column 4</T4Col4>
</Tab4>
another element than Tab4 might occur here...
<Tab4>
    <T4Head1>Second Table header 1</T4Head1>
    <T4Head2>Second Table header 2</T4Head2>
    <T4Head3>Second Table header 3</T4Head3>
    <T4Head4>Second Table header 4</T4Head4>
</Tab4>

<Tab4>
    <T4Col1>Second Table row 1 column 1</T4Col1>
    <T4Col2>Second Table row 1 column 2</T4Col2>
    <T4Col3>Second Table row 1 column 3</T4Col3>
    <T4Col4>Second Table row 1 column 4</T4Col4>
</Tab4>
<Tab4>
    <T4Col1>Second Table row 2 column 1</T4Col1>
    <T4Col2>Second Table row 2 column 2</T4Col2>
    <T4Col3>Second Table row 2 column 3</T4Col3>
    <T4Col4>Second Table row 2 column 4</T4Col4>
</Tab4>
<Tab4>
    <T4Col1>Second Table row 3 column 1</T4Col1>
    <T4Col2>Second Table row 3 column 2</T4Col2>
    <T4Col3>Second Table row 3 column 3</T4Col3>
    <T4Col4>Second Table row 3 column 4</T4Col4>
</Tab4>
another element than Tab4 might occur here...
```

With XSLT 1.0 I need to output html looking like below. In other words I need each Tab4 block containing T4Col1, T4Col2 etc to repeat until next kind of element occurs (not being Tab4/T4Col1).

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="specTab" border="1">
                <tbody>
                
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Table header 1
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Table header 2
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Table header 3
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Table header 4
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    
<!-- this part should repeat -->
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Table column 1
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Table column 2
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Table column 3
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Table column 4
                            </td>
                        </tr>
<!-- this part should repeat -->    

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I've had some tries but can't get grip of it. My current XSLT code looks like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="./node()">

    <xsl:choose>

        <!-- Multiple other test scenarios -->
        <xsl:when test="name()='Rub1' and . !=''">

        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="name()='Tab4' and ./T4Head1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table class="specTab" border="1">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="./T4Head1"/>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="./T4Head2"/>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="./T4Head3"/>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="./T4Head4"/>
                                </th>
                            </tr>

                            <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::node()/T4Col1">

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            </xsl:for-each>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:otherwise>

    </xsl:choose>

</xsl:for-each>
```

Problem with the code above is that it outputs all Tab4/T4Col1 (1+3), even the ones after next header occurrence. Somewhat I need to group header and all rows/columns since I want them to be in the same HTML-table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<root>
   <p>para 1</p>
   <Tab4>
      <T4Head1>First Table header 1</T4Head1>
      <T4Head2>First Table header 2</T4Head2>
      <T4Head3>First Table header 3</T4Head3>
      <T4Head4>First Table header 4</T4Head4>
   </Tab4>
   <Tab4>
      <T4Col1>First Table row 1 column 1</T4Col1>
      <T4Col2>First Table row 1 column 2</T4Col2>
      <T4Col3>First Table row 1 column 3</T4Col3>
      <T4Col4>First Table row 1 column 4</T4Col4>
   </Tab4>
   <p>para 2</p>
   <Tab4>
      <T4Head1>Second Table header 1</T4Head1>
      <T4Head2>Second Table header 2</T4Head2>
      <T4Head3>Second Table header 3</T4Head3>
      <T4Head4>Second Table header 4</T4Head4>
   </Tab4>
   <Tab4>
      <T4Col1>Second Table row 1 column 1</T4Col1>
      <T4Col2>Second Table row 1 column 2</T4Col2>
      <T4Col3>Second Table row 1 column 3</T4Col3>
      <T4Col4>Second Table row 1 column 4</T4Col4>
   </Tab4>
   <Tab4>
      <T4Col1>Second Table row 2 column 1</T4Col1>
      <T4Col2>Second Table row 2 column 2</T4Col2>
      <T4Col3>Second Table row 2 column 3</T4Col3>
      <T4Col4>Second Table row 2 column 4</T4Col4>
   </Tab4>
   <Tab4>
      <T4Col1>Second Table row 3 column 1</T4Col1>
      <T4Col2>Second Table row 3 column 2</T4Col2>
      <T4Col3>Second Table row 3 column 3</T4Col3>
      <T4Col4>Second Table row 3 column 4</T4Col4>
   </Tab4>
   <p>para 3</p>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="rows" match="Tab4[T4Col1]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::Tab4[T4Head1][1])" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Tab4[T4Head1]">
    <table  border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('rows', generate-id())">
                <tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Tab4[T4Col1]"/>

<xsl:template match="Tab4[T4Head1]/*">
    <th>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </th>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Tab4[T4Col1]/*">
    <td>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This uses a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)** to tie the body rows to their header row, so that they can be called by their header row's unique id.

The result will be:

```
<root>
   <p>para 1</p>
   <table border="1">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>First Table header 1</th>
            <th>First Table header 2</th>
            <th>First Table header 3</th>
            <th>First Table header 4</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>First Table row 1 column 1</td>
            <td>First Table row 1 column 2</td>
            <td>First Table row 1 column 3</td>
            <td>First Table row 1 column 4</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <p>para 2</p>
   <table border="1">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Second Table header 1</th>
            <th>Second Table header 2</th>
            <th>Second Table header 3</th>
            <th>Second Table header 4</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>Second Table row 1 column 1</td>
            <td>Second Table row 1 column 2</td>
            <td>Second Table row 1 column 3</td>
            <td>Second Table row 1 column 4</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Second Table row 2 column 1</td>
            <td>Second Table row 2 column 2</td>
            <td>Second Table row 2 column 3</td>
            <td>Second Table row 2 column 4</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Second Table row 3 column 1</td>
            <td>Second Table row 3 column 2</td>
            <td>Second Table row 3 column 3</td>
            <td>Second Table row 3 column 4</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <p>para 3</p>
</root>
```

rendered as:

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot! It saved my day and a lot of headache :)